# Merge a number of text files into one with next line for every file

Tags: files, merge

I have 2 files. I want to merge them.

File1 contents:

```
abc
```

File2 contents:

```
def
```

Combined File should be:

```
abc 
def
```

Comment: Its should ne new line for def

Answer (score 3):

This is a useful<sup>1</sup> use of [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29):

```
$ cat File1 File2 > CombinedFile
```

---

<sub>Footnotes:</sub>

<sub>1. As opposed to the [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)</sub>

Comment: I think he meant to take one line each time from both file, and merge them, not to append one file to another.

Comment: "Did you mean: useful" :)

Comment: @warl0ck Then he should have stated that.

Answer (score 0):

This perl scriptlet does this deed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open my $f1, "<", $ARGV[0];
open my $f2, "<", $ARGV[1];

do {
    $line1 = <$f1>;
    print $line1 if(defined($line1));
    $line2 = <$f2>;
    print $line2 if(defined($line2));
} while(defined($line1) && defined($line2));
while(<$f1>) {
    print;
}
while(<$f2>) {
    print;
}
```

Call as e.g. `perl splice file1 file2 > spliced`. Has *no* error checking, just a thowaway script.